# KEYWORD SeleniumLibrary . Element Should Be Visible username Documentation: Verifies that the element identified by locator is visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have HTML with multiple "username" classes and one of them is visible when first one is displayed: none.

My robot framework code is having trouble to input text to displayed "username" area because visible and not visible both have same "username" name.

I tried to use xpath, but it gies that error;

```
InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

f12 shows there is a form that includes displayed none and visible "username" fields:

```
<form id="fm1" action="/cas/login?autocomplete="off"> <section style="display: none"> <input id="username" style="display: none" type="text" name="username-breaker" autocomplete="off"> <input id="password" style="display: none" type="password" name="password-breaker" autocomplete="off"> </section> <section> <label for="username"><span class="accesskey">U</span>sername:</label> <input id="username" name="username" class="form-control" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" type="text" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off"> </section>
```

How can I input text to visible "username" area?

Comment: I add it to the question

Comment: //*[@id="fm1"]/section[2]/label

//*[@id="fm1"]/section[3]/label

Comment: solved!input text  name:username      ${username}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following inputs:

1. ```
   <input id="username" style="display: none" type="text" name="username-breaker" autocomplete="off">
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   this one is [not visible](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) therefore you cannot interact with it
2. ```
   <input id="username" name="username" class="form-control" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" type="text" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off">
   ```

   this one is visible and can be interacted

So you need to identify the input #2, it can be done using i.e. the following XPath expression:

```
//input[@id='username' and not(@style='display: none')]
```

Demo:

[image]

Even easier option would be sticking to [`name` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) like:

```
//input[@name='username']
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)